# Expected value of an increasing function...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions, probability-distributions, expectation

Assume that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a deterministic, increasing function (not necessarily strictly increasing).

Also, assume that $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are iid noise; i.e., for a distribution $g$, $\epsilon_1 \sim g$ and $\epsilon_2 \sim g$, and $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are independent.

We know that for known constants $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $a>b$, we have $$P_{g}(f(a+\epsilon_1)>f(b+\epsilon_2)) \geq P_{g}(f(a+\epsilon_1)<f(b+\epsilon_2)).$$

Now, if I know $$E_{g}[f(a+\epsilon_1)]>E_{g}[f(b+\epsilon_2)],$$ can I conclude:
$$P_{g}(f(a+\epsilon_1)>f(b+\epsilon_2)) > P_{g}(f(a+\epsilon_1)<f(b+\epsilon_2)).$$

Comment: What are $E_g$, $P_g$?

Comment: The probability and expected value computed over $g$. I wanted to show that the randomness is due to $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ which are distributed as $g$.

Comment: Sorry-there was a mistake in the question. Corrected it now.

Comment: The $\geq$ sign is replaced by $>$. I want to conclude that equality is not possible.

Comment: Why not? Can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, probably you can (forgot about the identical distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 
$$
P\big(f(a+\epsilon_1)>f(b+\epsilon_2)\big) = P\big(f(a+\epsilon_1)<f(b+\epsilon_2)\big),
$$
we have, taking complements and using the symmetry,
$$
P\big(f(a+\epsilon_1)\ge f(b+\epsilon_2)\big) = P\big(f(b+\epsilon_1)\ge f(a+\epsilon_2)\big).
$$
However (as you have pointed out), 
$$
P\big(f(a+\epsilon_1)\ge f(b+\epsilon_2)\big) \ge P\big(f(b+\epsilon_1)\ge f(b+\epsilon_2)\big)\ge P\big(f(b+\epsilon_1)\ge f(a+\epsilon_2)\big),
$$
so the left inequality must be equality. Therefore,
$$
P\big(f(a+\epsilon_1)\neq f(b+\epsilon_1), f(b+\epsilon_1)\ge f(b+\epsilon_2)\big) = 0.
$$
This yields, in view of independence, 
$$
P\big(f(a+\epsilon_1)\neq f(b+\epsilon_1), f(b+\epsilon_1)\ge f(b+x)\big) = 0
$$
for almost all $x\pmod{g}$. Letting $x\to \operatorname{essinf} \epsilon_1$, we get
$$
P\big(f(a+\epsilon_1)= f(b+\epsilon_1)\big) = 1.
$$
Consequently,
$$
E\big(f(a+\epsilon_1)\big)= E\big(f(b+\epsilon_1)\big) = E\big(f(b+\epsilon_2)\big),
$$
a contradiction.

I believe there is a simpler argument (because the statement is quite obvious), but I do not see it.